# Create hyperlink in react native for Android

Tags: react-native

**Update**: looks like this is implemented now with `IntentAndroid`! https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/intentandroid.html#content

--  original post  --

I am writing an Android app with React Native. I would like to display a hyperlink that will launch the user's default browser and open the linked URL. How can I do this?

There is `LinkingIOS` for iOS apps, is there some equivalent for Android?

Or am I going to have to create a component that wraps something like this (Java):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK it looks like what I wanted isn't a react component just yet, but I found this awesome component that is exactly what I want: https://github.com/ivanph/react-native-webintent/